# Breaking down/reusing complex calculations in a Transact SQL view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

In a SQL view, what is the best way to handle the problem of reusing previous calculations such that they do not become complex/unreadable.

In a stored proc, we could store/output @variables and do the calcs using them as we went along, but my problem is that this must be done in a view.

What's the best way to go about this? (bearing in mind there are a few thousand rows of data).

```
SELECT  
        /* CALC 1 output to view row */
        (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency/dbo.[Contract].Value * 
            (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Invoice.ValueInContractCurrency),0)
             FROM dbo.Invoice 
             WHERE dbo.Invoice.StageId = Act.StageId)) AS InvoicedValueInContractCurrency, 

        /* CALC 2 wraps CALC1 inside it and outputs to view row */
        (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency - 
            (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency/dbo.[Contract].Value * 
                (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Invoice.ValueInContractCurrency),0)
                 FROM dbo.Invoice 
                 WHERE dbo.Invoice.StageId = Act.StageId))) AS RemainingValueInContractCurrency,        

        /* CALC 3 wraps CALC2 inside it (which in turn wraps CALC1) and outputs to view row */
        (SELECT ConCurrency.CurrentExchangeRate / dbo.[Contract].CostedExchangeRate *
            (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency - 
                (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency/dbo.[Contract].Value * 
                    (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Invoice.ValueInContractCurrency),0)
                     FROM dbo.Invoice 
                     WHERE dbo.Invoice.StageId = Act.StageId)))) AS RemainingValueInFacilityCurrency

        /* etc... for 10 more calcs that get increasingly long and unreadable via wrapping */

        FROM dbo.Activity AS Act
        JOIN dbo.Stage ON Act.StageId = dbo.Stage.Id       
        JOIN dbo.[Contract] ON dbo.Stage.ContractId = dbo.[Contract].Id
        JOIN dbo.Facility  ON dbo.[Contract].FacilityId = Facility.Id
        JOIN dbo.Currency AS FacCurrency ON dbo.Facility.CurrencyId = FacCurrency.Id
        JOIN dbo.Currency AS ConCurrency ON dbo.[Contract].CurrencyId = ConCurrency.Id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just subquery them. Although to be honest, SQL Server sees through the "wraps" and does reuse the expressions; you can verify that by checking the execution plan.

```
        /* etc... for 10 more calcs that get increasingly long and unreadable via wrapping */

SELECT  *,
        /* CALC 3 wraps CALC2 inside it (which in turn wraps CALC1) and outputs to view row */
        (SELECT CurrentExchangeRate / CostedExchangeRate *
            RemainingValueInContractCurrency) AS RemainingValueInFacilityCurrency
FROM (
SELECT  *,
        /* CALC 2 wraps CALC1 inside it and outputs to view row */
        (SELECT ValueInContractCurrency - 
            InvoicedValueInContractCurrency) AS RemainingValueInContractCurrency
FROM (
SELECT  *,  
        /* CALC 1 output to view row */
        (SELECT Act.ValueInContractCurrency/dbo.[Contract].Value * 
            (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Invoice.ValueInContractCurrency),0)
             FROM dbo.Invoice 
             WHERE dbo.Invoice.StageId = Act.StageId)) AS InvoicedValueInContractCurrency
        FROM dbo.Activity AS Act
        JOIN dbo.Stage ON Act.StageId = dbo.Stage.Id       
        JOIN dbo.[Contract] ON dbo.Stage.ContractId = dbo.[Contract].Id
        JOIN dbo.Facility  ON dbo.[Contract].FacilityId = Facility.Id
        JOIN dbo.Currency AS FacCurrency ON dbo.Facility.CurrencyId = FacCurrency.Id
        JOIN dbo.Currency AS ConCurrency ON dbo.[Contract].CurrencyId = ConCurrency.Id
        ) A
        ) B
```

Comment: tried running it quickly as you typed it and got this: Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'A'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "Act.ValueInContractCurrency" could not be bound.
Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'B'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "ConCurrency.CurrentExchangeRate" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The multi-part identifier "dbo.Contract.CostedExchangeRate" could not be bound.

Comment: My apologies. Query updated. At the innermost level, make sure ALL the columns you require in the calculations are included, and if duplicate column names exist (between tables), you will need to alias them. At the outer queries, use the column names directly without table alias.

Comment: All sorted now. Marked as answer. Thanks very much.